# How do I populate DataGridView row by row where each row represents a json api response?

Tags: c#, json, datagridview

In my code below, I'm trying to get several json API responses and take each of these and put them in a new DataGridView row (populating at first row). I have seen ways of doing this using DataTable as DataSource, but in my case, I have only managed to populate the DataGridView without using DataTable. So, is there a way to use my existing code and solve this problem or do I have to use DataTable as DataSource? And if using DataTablel is the only way of doing it, how do I change my code to make it work?

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    using (var client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        var values = new NameValueCollection();
                        values["apikey"] = "my api key";
                        string destination = @"http://www.xxxxxx.xx/xx/api/?command=show&id=" + i + "";
                        var response = client.UploadValues(destination, values);

                        string responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);

                        var jobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responseString);
                        var jsString = jobj["return"].ToString();
                        var token = JToken.Parse(jsString);

                        if (token is JArray)
                        {
                            DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1b.Rows[0].Clone();
                            dataGridView1b.Rows.Add(row);
                            var results = token.ToObject<List<JsonResult>>();
                            dataGridView1b.DataSource = results;

                        }
                        else if (token is JObject)
                        {
                            DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1b.Rows[0].Clone();
                            dataGridView1b.Rows.Add(row);
                            var result = token.ToObject<JsonResult>();
                            var results = new List<JsonResult>();
                            results.Add(result);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This is how the json looks like.

```
{"error":"","return":{"key":"value","key":"value","key":"value"}}
```

I'm getting each json by using a for loop and the DataGridView is then populated with these json values. With this way of doing it, the DataGridView first row is populated over and over again, so it ends up with only the last populated values.

Comment: You don't need to use a `DataTable`, you can use anything [listed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks). My advice is to not manipulate the rows at all, let databinding do that work. Create a suitable data source and bind it to the grid. IMO any time you are manipulating UI elements directly you are doing too much work.

Comment: @Crowcoder-Thank you for your answer. I've tried to come up with a working solution for a couple of days now, but I can't get it to work. I have looked into the subject of databinding as you pointed out, but I can't put it together, so it works with my code. I have not much experience in programming so it's hard to understand what's going on and adjust the code thereafter. I have tried searching for an answer to a similar problem of mine but without any luck.
I would be very happy if you could point me to a more precise direction or if you have some code example.

Comment: @Crowcode - I have managed to get it to work, so you don't have to answer my previous comment.